# JS addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I apologize in advance for this simple question but its late and I don't want to sleep until I have it working...and I know my mind is numb from working on other parts for last many hours.

Basically, I am just trying to get the submit button to call the `add()` function by assigning it with `addEventListener`. When I click the button it clears the form but doesn't do anything else. If I fill in the fields and then call `add()` in Chrome's JS console it works perfectly...clearly the event listener is not being added to the button and I don't want to call the function inline. Thanks in advance.

html:

> ```
>     <ul>
>         <li>
>             <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
>             <input type="text" id="firstname"/>
>         </li>
>         <li>
>             <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
>             <input type="text" id="lastname"/>
>         </li>
>         <li>
>             <label for="email">Email:</label>
>             <input type="text" id="email"/>
>         </li>
>         <li>
>             <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
>             <input type="text" id="subject"/>
>         </li>
>         <li>
>             <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave"/>
>         </li>
>     </ul>
> ```

JS:

```
var rolodex = localStorage.getItem('rolodex'); //load stored data if there is any

window.onload = function() {
    rolodex = JSON.parse(rolodex);
    if(rolodex === null) { //if no data, initialize an empty array
        rolodex = [];
    } else {
    console.log(rolodex);
    }
};

var add = function(){
    var SME = JSON.stringify({
        firstname:document.getElementById('firstname').value,
        lastname:document.getElementById('lastname').value,
        email:document.getElementById('email').value,
        subject:document.getElementById('subject').value
    });

    rolodex.push(SME);
    localStorage.setItem('rolodex', JSON.stringify(rolodex));
    alert("Saved");
};

var submit = function(){
    var btnSave = document.getElementById('btnSave');
    btnSave.addEventListener('click', add(), false);
};
```

Comment: Sorry I can't replicate on my phone, but have you tried implicitly adding the listener for submit.

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted a partial answer and then deleted it so I will put what I did.

1. Fixed `add()` being called instead of assigned as just `add` in the `addEventListener`
2. removed the submit function and put its contents in the `window.onLoad` function so that it would be assigned automatically.